# Error invalid type argument of '--->' (have 'int')

Tags: c

Bueno pues me encuentro haciendo un programa de ficheros en el que necesito usar varias funciones para hacer distintas cosas pero cuando uso el comando feof para leer todo el fichero me salta el error del titulo , he estado probando cosas pero nada parece arreglarlo , si no no se me ocurre otra forma para leer un archivo sin ese comando. Dejo el codigo , gracias:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main(){
    char archivo1[50],archivo2[50],fecha[20],A[10];
    FILE *f1,*f2;
abrirfichero(archivo1,archivo2,fecha,A,f1,f2);
leerdatosalumno(f1,f2);
}
void abrirfichero(archivo1,archivo2,fecha,A,f1,f2)
{

    printf("Escribe el nombre del archivo de entrada:");
    scanf("%s",archivo1);
    f1=fopen(archivo1,"r");
    if (f1==NULL){
            printf("Error");
            }
    printf("Escribe el nombre del archivo de salida:");
    scanf("%s",archivo2);
    f2=fopen(archivo2,"r");
       if (f2==NULL){
            printf("Error");
            }
fseek( f2, 0, SEEK_END );
if (ftell(f2) != 0 )
{
printf("Fichero con cosas, quiere escrbir algo mas o hacer uno nuevo:");
scanf("%s",A);
if(A='a'){
    f2=fopen(archivo2,"a");
}
if(A='w'){
    f2=fopen(archivo2,"w");
}
}
}

void leerdatosalumno(f1,f2){
char DNI[9],nombre[50],apellido[50],cadena[100];
int i=0;
while(fgets(nombre,100,f1)!= NULL){


}

}
```

Comment: El código tiene muchos errores. Nunca especificas los tipos de cada parámetro. Los argumentos se están pasando por valor, por lo tanto, los punteros `f1` y `f2` nunca serán actualizados por la función `abrirfichero`.

Comment: Si a esa conclusion he llegado , pero como especifico el tipo de parametro que es f1 y f2

Comment: Por ejemplo: `void leerdatosalumno(FILE** f1, FILE** f2) { ... }` En este [enlace](http://programandoenc.over-blog.es/article-32481588.html) explican más sobre funciones en C. El tipo de dato de cada parámetro se lo antepone en el nombre. En el ejemplo, el tipo es `FILE**`.